# How do you change the Swagger favicon?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1

I am building a ASP.NET CORE Web API and using Swagger for the documentation. I have not been able to change the favicon. I have a swagger-ui directory under wwwroot where I have placed my favicon but the favicon is never there. Also, I am changing the favicon using favascript in a custom js file.

So, how does one change the favicon for Swagger?

Answer (score 14):

You need to inject jscript as below:

1- Create  /assets/js/docs.js as below:

```
(function() {
    var link = document.querySelector("link[rel*='icon']") || document.createElement('link');;
    document.head.removeChild(link);
    link = document.querySelector("link[rel*='icon']") || document.createElement('link');
    document.head.removeChild(link);
    link = document.createElement('link');
    link.type = 'image/x-icon';
    link.rel = 'shortcut icon';
    link.href = '../assets/images/logo_icon.png';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
})();
```

2- Load the script in your startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider)
        {
            app.UseSwaggerUI(
                options =>
                {                    
                    options.InjectJavascript("../assets/js/docs.js");  
                });

        }
```

Note: Make sure you enable static files in your .NET Core Configure method.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider)
{

    app.UseStaticFiles(); // For the wwwroot folder

    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "assets/images")),
        RequestPath = "/assets/images"
    });        

    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "assets/js")),
        RequestPath = "/assets/js"
    });
```

}

Comment: The above JS worked for me. Only thing is there is a short period where it still shows the default until the JS is run.

Answer (score 7):

This is what worked for me:

First, you have to create the wwwroot folder, and place there a folder called swagger. Edit your csproj to include this line:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="wwwroot\*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Files under this directory must be `Content`, `Do not copy`. That's default option anyway.

Then, you have to place two png files called `favicon-16x16.png` and `favicon-32x32.png` in swagger folder.

Last thig to do, add `app.UseStaticFiles();` before `app.UseSwaggerUI();` to get it to work.

You can also add a favicon.ico under wwwroot folder.

** NOTE: In case you had modified endpoint url, using `app.UseSwaggerUI(config => config.SwaggerEndpoint("my/swagger/doc/file.json", "Rest API"));`, directory tree under wwwroot must match the url. i.e., `wwwroot/my/swagger/doc/favicon-16x16.png` and `wwwroot/my/swagger/doc/favicon-32x32.png`.

Comment: This ended up being my issue.. `add app.UseStaticFiles(); before app.UseSwaggerUI(); to get it to work`. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

This can also be achieved if you simply place your favicon.ico at the root within wwwroot folder: `wwwroot/favicon.ico`.  Being placed at the root, the favicon.ico will be used as the default browser tab icon.

Of course as previously stated, you need to make sure you have `app.UseStaticFiles();` in your Configure() method in order to serve the files within wwwroot.

Lastly also make sure you have the following in your .csproj file:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="wwwroot\*" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to essentially override it. By default, Swagger UI sets the icon to pull from your Swagger UI root. For example, if you load the docs at `/swagger-ui`, then the favicon is being pulled from `/swagger-ui/favicon-32x32.png` and `/swagger-ui/favicon-16x16.png`. Therefore, you can add this directory to your `wwwroot` and add your own favicon images there.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! In my project, I have the png files uner the swagger-ui directory. However, when I run my project under localhost the png files are not under my swagger-ui directory. Any thoughts on why they are missing?

Comment: Change the directory name from `swagger-ui` to `swagger` and put the two png files by the same name stated above.

Comment: The above did not work for me. In fact I could see it getting the above image images from `<url root>/swagger/ui/images` so I put them there, but I still get the default swagger icon in the browser tab. I am not using asp.core though (it is just asp.net), so not sure if that changes things..

Answer (score 0):

For ASP.NET Core (Web API and MVC), if you use `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` to generate Swagger (the question doesn't specify), you don't need to have a `wwwroot` at all to achieve this. You can inject custom html into the document `<head>` by using Swashbuckle `HeadContent` and provide your own icon.

Swashbuckle will provide its own default icon, but when enabling Swashbuckle, configure `HeadContent` like this:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(options => {
    options.HeadContent = "<link rel=\"icon\" type=\"image/png\" href=\"https://site/favicon.ico\" sizes=\"16x16\"
```

If you want to inject a local icon, you need a `wwwroot`.

If not using Swashbuckle, the method may be different.